# How to select background color in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

can any budy explain how to select background color from

```
<div class="shc" style="background-color:#814c1b;">About Me</div>
```

in selenium.
i've source code like this

```
<div class="gwt-Label mock-tab selected-tab">My Account</div>
```

and i need to select color from it.
i'm using firebug to get xpath or css.

i'm using python and i'm new to selenium. please help.

Comment: show me the python code with selenium you have so far, then I can and will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer which i finally got for all color, font size and alignment related questions. Thx for all who tried to help.

```
sel.get_eval("el = this.browserbot.findElement('xpath or css'); bold
=window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue('font-weight');")
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Javascript:**

```
var xx = document.getElementsByClassName("gwt-Label");
var bgColorIs = xx[0].style.backgroundColor
```

**With CSS Selectors**

```
div.gwt-Label.mock-tab.selected-tab.background-color
```

**XPath:**

[div@class='gwt-Label mock-tab selected-tab']

[XPath samples](https://web.archive.org/web/20140715142631/http://wiki.novell.com:80/index.php/XPATH_Examples)

[CSS Selectors by Class](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html)

[Javascript - getting an element by class name or tag name](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html)

Comment: can you give same code using python cos i dont know javascript.

Comment: sure how are you parsing this HTML? Are you using BeautifulSoup (a library for Python to parse HTML)?

Comment: i din get ur point? and in python we don've library called getElementsByClassName. i used get_attribue().

Comment: Can you post your current Python code, so that we see how you are trying to parse the HTML.

Comment: this is my code.    class Oak_STAK_Verifycolor(object):
    '''
    This function is to verify color.
    '''


    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def do(self,selobj,parameter,ExpectedValue):
 org = selobj.get_attribute(parameter)
 print org
 print ExpectedValue
        if(ExpectedValue == org):
            return True
        else:
            return False

Comment: i use selenium library instead of webdriver.is der any way so det i can create my function which contains find_elements_by_class_name(parameter1) in selenium.py file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value_of_css_property` on the element after you find it. Something like:

```
current_element = sel.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.shc')
background_color = current_element.value_of_css_property('background-color')
```